# Java splitting separating imaginary and real part of a Complex number

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to write a program to perform arithmetic operations on Complex numbers. The complex numbers are given in input as String. I want to convert the string into real and imaginary part. I needed help in doing that.

[image: This image shows the basic GUI of the program]

Below code is what I have been trying

```
             public float getreal(String c){
                //String s[] = c.split("[\\Q+-\\Ei]");

                 //System.out.println(s[0]+" "+s[1]);

                 int postion_plus=c.indexOf('+');
                 int position_i=c.indexOf('i');
                 System.out.println(c.substring(0, postion_plus));
                 return Float.parseFloat(c.substring(0,postion_plus));


             }
```

The code seems to work for positive number but it throws error for negative complex numbers like   -5.5+4i

This code is just to get the real part

Comment: your code works fine for me...

  String c = "-5.5+4i";
  int postion_plus=c.indexOf('+');
  float f = Float.parseFloat(c.substring(0,postion_plus));
  System.out.println(f);

>> -5.5

Comment: It won't work for numbers with negative imaginary part, like `5.5-4i`.

Comment: When it comes to parsing, it's quickly becoming important to answer the question: Which input should be allowed? Something like `-4-3i` should work, but what about `4 + -3i`, `+4+3i`, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] okSamples = {"3", "-1.0", "7i", "i", "+i", "-i", "4-7i", "-3.4i", ".5", "3."};
String[] badSamples = {"", "1.0.5i", "+", "-"};



String doubleRegex = "[-+]?(\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)";
Pattern doublePattern = Pattern.compile(doubleRegex);
```

For a total pattern the cases are too cumbersome to get it right and cover most cases:

```
// Not okay:
Pattern complexPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<re>" + doubleRegex + "?)"
                                       + "(?<im>((" + doubleRegex + "i|[-+]?i))?)";
```

So handle the cases in code. For instance something like:

```
double re = 0.0;
double im = 0.0;
Matcher m = doublePattern.matcher(c);
if (m.lookingAt()) {
    re = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
    c = c.substring(m.end());
    m = doublePattern.matcher(c);
    if (c.matches("[-+].*") && m.lookingAt()) {
        im = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
        c = c.substring(m.end());
        if (!c.equals("i")) {
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
    } else if (c.matches("[-+]i")) {
        im = c.startsWith("-") ? -1.0 : 1.0;
    } else {
        throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
} else if (c.matches("[-+]i")) {
    im = c.startsWith("-") ? -1.0 : 1.0;
} else {
    throw new NumberFormatException();
}
```

This handles the retrieval more solidly. `lookingAt` does a partial match from the start of the string.

Comment: I have a long-lasting challenge for RegEx fans: Find a RegEx that matches `double` values (according to the JLS, *maybe* excluding `NaN`). The given one fails for `1e10`. (It may not be relevant for the asker, though, but I think that others might *assume* that the given pattern matches `double` (and I think that RegEx is not the right approach here, but wouldn't like to argue about that))

Comment: @Marco13 that is with underscore and all. Doable given the specification. But babelonian ugly.